# Difficulty with running PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

From PyQt4.QtGui Cannot import module uic

I cannot seem to find this uic module to download or install it. I think it's suppose to come with the qt4 and qt designer packages.

Comment: It's supposed to be `from PyQt4 import uic`, see the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#the-uic-module)

Answer (score 0):

uic would be a c++ rather than a python command.
I’m guessing you want to convert qt file to a python compatible file if that is the case simply open a terminal and navigate to the directory where your Qt file is and the enter the following:
$ pyuic your_file.ui -o your_file.py
you should now have in the same directory a .py file which you can incorporate in your project

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks guys.